# Traer todo desde MySql con PHP y mostrar en JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo un problema con PHP y JSON. Lo que hago es tratar de traer todos los datos desde la base de datos, pero solo me muestra el primero. Si pongo un WHERE me trae el correcto pero yo quiero todos y solo me trae el primero. No entiendo cual puede ser el error agradezco su ayuda.

```
$hostname_localhost="localhost";
$database_localhost="drive";
$username_localhost="root";
$password_localhost="";

$json=array();

 $conexion = new mysqli($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost,   $password_localhost, $database_localhost);    

 $consulta="SELECT * FROM comercio";

 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

 if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
     $json['comercios'][]=$registro;  

 }else{
     $resultar["comercios"]=0; 
 }

mysqli_close($conexion);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: has probado $json = json_encode($resultado,true)?

Comment: Eso es un array, no puede imprimirlo como tal, tienes que recorrerlo con un bucle.

Comment: Gracias @PavloB.Habia que recorrerlo !

Comment: Si queres podrías contestar tu propia pregunta en dado caso alguien se encuentre en situación que pasaste.

Answer (score 1):

La solución es recorrer el array de la db e ir pasandolo al JSON. Sino solo agarrará el primer dato.

```
$hostname_localhost="localhost";
$database_localhost="drive";
$username_localhost="root";
$password_localhost="";

$json=array();

  $conexion = new mysqli($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);    

  $consulta="SELECT * FROM comercio";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

     while($registro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
         $json['comercios'][]=$registro;  

     }

    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

$hostname_localhost="localhost";
$database_localhost="drive";
$username_localhost="root";
$password_localhost="";

$json=array();

$conexion = new mysqli($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);

$consulta="SELECT * FROM comercio";

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

 while($registro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
     $json['comercios'][]=$registro;  

 }

mysqli_close($conexion);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: lo mismo que te comenté en otra publicación por favor explica el código; además de eso selecciónalo todo y dale clic al icono `{}` para que se vea formateado